# How to merge array field in the documents in mongoldb

Tags: mongodb

My documents  looks like this

```
[{
 "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2021-12-24T11:58:05.058Z"
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "slots": [{
        "isBooked": "true",
        "time": "11:15",
        "date": "2021-12-26"
    }]
},{
 "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2021-12-24T11:58:05.058Z"
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "slots": [{
        "isBooked": "true",
        "time": "11:15",
        "date": "2021-12-26"
    }]
}]
```

When doing aggregate operation  like below ,I am trying concat ,merge ,but nothin works

```
Staff.aggregate([
        {
            $match:{vendorId:payload._id,"slots.date": payload.serviceDate }
        }
,
       {
            $project:{
               
                _id:0,
                slots:1
            }
        },

       // { $project: { items: { $concatArrays:"$slots" } } }
      //  { $unwind: "$slots" },
       // {$group: { _id: "$slots"}},
       // { $merge : { into : "data", on: "slots" } },
      //  {$project: { _id: 0,slots: "$_id"} },
        

    ])
```

I am getting output like below

```
//[{"slots":[{"isBooked":"true","time":"11:15","date":"2021-12-26"}]},{"slots":[{"time":"08:00","date":"2021-12-26","isBooked":"true"}]}]
```

I want output something like below in a single slots array

```
[{"slots":[{"isBooked":"true","time":"11:15","date":"2021-12-26"},{"time":"08:00","date":"2021-12-26","isBooked":"true"}]}]
```

How to achieve this

Comment: Why not just use : concatArrays from mongodb documentation ? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/

Comment: Doesn't works @Sanixdarker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- concat all the arrays of each document in the collection into a single array
- group to get each array in `[[...] [...]]`
- reduce and concat those to flatten them
- concat is not accumulator so we need 2 steps group+reduce

*i don't know if you need this, this will concat all arrays that pass the first match, also `"slots.date": payload.serviceDate` passes if the slots has at least one member that makes the filter true, if you want only those dates to keep, you need to filter first each array.

[Test code](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70487538-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match":{"vendorId":payload._id,"slots.date": payload.serviceDate}}
 {"$group":{"_id":null, "slots":{"$push":"$slots"}}},
 {"$project":
  {"_id":0,
   "slots":
   {"$reduce":
    {"input":"$slots",
     "initialValue":[],
     "in":{"$concatArrays":["$$value", "$$this"]}}}}}])
```